# How to use Subsonic 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, subsonic, data-access-layer

i try to use subsonic 3.0 but i can not do that. i decided to use subsonic.2.0. So i try to make it i can not :(

my Web Config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="SubSonicService"
             type="SubSonic.SubSonicSection, SubSonic" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AdventureWorks"
      connectionString="Data Source=.;Database=eticaret;
                          Integrated Security=true; User ID=sa; Password=123456;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <SubSonicService defaultProvider="eticaret">
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="eticaret" type="SubSonic.SqlDataProvider, SubSonic"
        connectionStringName="eticaret"
        generatedNamespace="eticaretDAL"/>
    </providers>
  </SubSonicService>
</configuration>
```

also look this article: what is error? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SubsonicDAL.aspx

Comment: You're going to need to provide a LOT more information.  "What is error?"  When you tell US that we can try to help, we can't see your entire code and we don't automatically know exactly what you're working on.  What errors are you getting?  Why is it not working?  What are you trying to achieve?  Whhat have you already tried?  What didn't work in 3.0?

Comment: "You are doing something wrong" whould be as good of an answer as this question is.

Answer (score 1):

Change your connectionStringName in "AdventureWorks" in the add element. Like so:

```
<SubSonicService defaultProvider="eticaret">
<providers>
  <add name="eticaret" type="SubSonic.SqlDataProvider, SubSonic"
    connectionStringName="AdventureWorks"
```